# Asymptotic expansion of an integral involving hypergeometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

I need to consider
$$
\int_0^\infty d\tau \ \ {}_2F_1\left(\Delta, \Delta, 2\,\Delta, -A \cosh^2\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)
\right),\qquad A>0,\ \Delta>0
$$
and I am interested in the asymptotic expansion for $\Delta\to 0^+$. So what is needed is a uniform approximation. The naive expansion at small $\Delta$ is clearly useless because of the infinite integration range. On the other hand, using an expansion for large negative last argument and fixed first three is also bad when one attempts to take $\Delta\to 0$ in the end. Any suggestion ?

Comment: thanks Johannes, but the result in terms of Meijer function is quite useless. For instance, with Mathematica 11, I cannot expand the result around $\Delta$=0. Actually I was hoping for a method able to handle the $\Delta\to 0$ expansion without going through the exact definite integral.

Comment: (I deleted my first comment because of multiple typos: I wrote that I have a solution in terms of Meijer$G$ function.) I agree. The comment function did not let me finish my comment. I found the asymptotics of your integral, (I call it $I(\Delta, A)$) using the integral expression of the Meijer $G$ function, but need some time to write it down in MO style. The result for vanishing $\Delta$ and $A>0$ is $I(\Delta,A)\sim \frac{3}{2 \Delta}-\ln \frac{A}{4}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately, I was hoping for a method dealing with a class of cases to which the integral in my question belongs (and is the simplest). Other cases are for instance

Comment: $$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau \ \ \frac{1}{e^\tau+B}{}_2F_1\left(\Delta, \Delta, 2\,\Delta, -A \cosh^2\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)
\right),\qquad A, B>0,\ \Delta>0
$$ I think one should need a general way to get a uniform expansion of the hypergeometric function valid for $\Delta\to 0$ and $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$.